# No-IP (Public IP) is painfully slow compared to direct IP address access

Tags: ip, tcpip, vb.net

So I was making a software that sends screen image continuously using VB.NET (TCP) and when I type in my local IP address it sends screen image really fast but when I  changed it into my public IP address (or [No-IP](https://www.noip.com) address) it becomes painfully slow. Can someone help me out?

Video demonstration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Xcx8Azx2M8

Comment: Are you accessing your streamed screen outside your LAN (i.e. over the internet)? It would go slowly if your upload speed is low (most broadband connections have excellent download speeds but extremely poor upload speeds) so the upstream rate will be what is causing your application to be slow...

Comment: Well, I tested the public IP address on my own network (which means I'm very near the router. Or in other words, I tested the software on the same computer that I'm opening the server). The result as I told earlier, LAN IP (Private IP) is faster than Public IP and I find it rather weird. You can see the video at here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Xcx8Azx2M8
As you can see in the first part, I was using my local IP address (Private IP) and the frame rate is pretty quick. But in the second part, I used my public IP address and the frame rate just dropped instantly. And that's really weird.

Comment: Have you done things like a [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute)—or better yet use [MTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software)) (My Traceroute)—to see if you can see a point where data slows down?

Comment: I don't even know any of these, let alone using them :P

Comment: @HồMinhQuân Those are command line tools. Unsure what OS you are on, but follow those links and read up. In general, you would just use them like this for traceroute, `traceroute example.com` or for MTR like this `mtr example.com`. And of course change `example.com` to match your IP address as well as your No-IP hostname.

Comment: So I have to use those commands when i'm running the software?

Comment: @HồMinhQuân No. You should read the links. They are tools that can help you diagnose networking issues. Also, note that your video link is dead; I just get “This video is unavailable.”

Comment: @JakeGould What does this have to mean? https://i.imgur.com/A0FSCsK.png

Comment: @JakeGould Oh and sorry, I set my video to private earlier. I set it back to public.

Comment: There isn't any networking issues, I'm still left with a big 0. One thing I noticed is that  when I slow down the sending speed rate of the client, the software seems to have a little bit better frame rate (not that much). Maybe the software receiving the data is overloaded?